# Getting error exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When i run the following class files in selenium, the browser is launched and URL is opened but error after that:

```
exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at guru99project.guru99project.printtitlepage(guru99project.java:25)
    at guru99project.Main_method.main(Main_method.java:10)
```

Code trials:

```
package guru99project;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class guru99project {

 public WebDriver driver;

    public void invokechrome() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\A\\eclipse-workspace\\libs\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        Dimension dim = new Dimension(640,480);
        driver.manage().window().setSize(dim);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/v4");            
    }

    public void printtitlepage() {

        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());      
    }

    public void login (String uname, String pwd) {
        WebElement usid = driver.findElement(By.name("uid"));       
        usid.sendKeys(uname);

     //   driver.findElement(By.name("uid")).sendKeys(uname);
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(pwd);
        driver.findElement(By.name("btnLogin")).click();



    }

}

    package guru99project;

public class Main_method {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        guru99project gp = new guru99project();

        gp.invokechrome();
        gp.printtitlepage();
        gp.login("mnr160177", "hynydej");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have defined **driver** as an instance of **WebDriver** globally (Class level) as:

```
public WebDriver driver;
```

So you don't need to define any other new instance of **WebDriver** within any of the `methods()` within the same *Class* and keep on using the same globally defined instance of **WebDriver** i.e *driver*.

You need to remove **WebDriver** from the line:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

So line would be:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

You Already Specified as `public WebDriver driver;`

so you No Need to Specify again as ,

```
Webdriver driver = new ChromeDriver();//if you need This , Then Don't Specify public Webdriver driver at the Top. Initialize here it self and Import it.
```

Please Change The Above Line as ,

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```